# How to make my Firebase custom event log in Android App?

Tags: android, firebase, event-log, firebase-analytics

I want to add a simple firebase event log to tell me when a certain event occurs.  This event is when my app sets a notification to go off.  What code would I use for this and where would I put the code.  My app is already set up to log the standard firebase analytics.  Thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 1):

> What code would I use for this

Here is sample method that sends an event associated with a value :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics;

public class EventHelper {

    public static void logEvent(Context context, String eventType, int value) {
        FirebaseAnalytics firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle() ;
        bundle.putInt(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.VALUE, value);
        firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(eventType, bundle);
    }
}
```

Note that this is more a snippet than a fully polished Helper.

> and where would I put the code.

Just put it when the event occurs... Firebase will take care of the rest. For instance, you can call it from an activity:

```
   EventHelper.logEvent(this, "item_purchased", amountInEuros);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do I make the first bit of code (EvenHelper Class) as it's own class file? Then call it from my activity where the notification event occurs that I want to log in firebase

Comment: Also could you explain what "item_purchasd" and amountInEuros does in the code?  I'm assuming that is what gets sent to firbase?  can I replace them with say "school name", schoolName  where schoolName is a string variable I have declared?

Comment: @user3718236 EventHelper: it's just a convenient helper if (like me) you have different events that all have a value - Don't forget that value are special parameters, they are accumulated for each user.

Comment: @user3718236 This is just a sample - "item_purchased" is the event key, while amountInEuros is the value (int variable) of the event. Don't mix the event type (in your case something like "user_registred_in_school", and the event attributes "school name", "school location", "school email", ...). Again these are just samples, I am not aware of your specific business.